# Getting the ID or name of a field on a parent entry that holds a Playa relationship

Tags: playa

Using the parents() method of Playa, is it possible to get the name or ID of the field in the parent that holds the relationship?

```
{exp:playa:parents entry_id="1" channel="my_channel"}
    parent field name or id = {????}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to ask what you're really trying to achieve. You probably don't need to know the field id.

Comment: Have tried to sum up in one line...

Comment: Yeah, but why would you need the field's id or name in the first place? Maybe there is a better way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the {entry_id} tag what you're looking for?

`{exp:playa:parents entry_id="1" channel="my_channel"}
   {entry_id}
{/exp:playa:parents}`

Within the context of `{exp:playa:parents}`, it will refer to the parent's id.

**Edit**

It's entirely not possible to get at the field_id of the parent that holds the relationship with the way EE and Playa are both architected.

Comment: I think he wants the field id where the relationship was made, not the entry id.

Comment: @jason-varga is right - it's the name or ID of the field in which the relationship is made. Use case is a parent entry in a Foo channel that has two Playa fields that can contain links to a Bar channel. When displaying my Bar entry I can see that there is a parent Foo entry, but I need to know which Playa field holds that relationship.